# Custom SurfaceView with thread crashes App when Activity is exited

Tags: android, surfaceview

I just made an Activity which uses at "setContentView" a view from a class which extends SurfaceView. The problem is:
It works fine, but when I exit it (BACK key) it crashes. Code:

```
package ro.etrandafir.mate.appCreator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class Sample2 extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    float x = 0, y = 0;
    SampleTwoView theView;

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
    theView = new SampleTwoView(this);
        theView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(theView);
    }

    public class SampleTwoView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Paint p = new Paint();

        public SampleTwoView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            Thread theThread = new Thread(this);
            theThread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (!getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) continue;
                Canvas canvas;
                canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
                if ((x != 0) && (y != 0)) canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 40, p);
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do? Should I add onDestroy or what?

Thanks in advance,
Matei

Comment: please post your logcat stack trace.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: So I should set while(boolean var) and change var to false in onPause?

Comment: yes a solution could be to make that not a while(true) and instead a while(boolean), and make sure to check that the canvas isn't null before `drawColor` is called.

Comment: you might also want to move the runnable logic out of the surface view but the boolean solution will likely work for now. ill think about it a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are getting is related to this code:

```
Canvas canvas;
canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
```

When your activity ends, your thread is still running, but your custom `SurfaceView` is no longer available, so you will get a null ptr exception. Your existing code can easily be patched by adding a boolean that gets set to false as soon as the `onPause` fn gets called:

```
public void run() {
    while (booleanThatGetsSetToFalseWhenActivityPauses) {
        if (!getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) continue;
        Canvas canvas;
        canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        if ((x != 0) && (y != 0)) canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 40, p);
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest altering the structure of your application as a whole. This may just be for practice, but I think a more efficient and bug free way of accomplishing your goal would be to simply use a standard `SurfaceView` and to completely decouple your drawing logic from any custom view.

---

My redesigned activity is below, but it utilizes a `Ball` class that is used to maintain the ball's logic, which, in your current code is separately coupled with both the actvity (the coordinates) and the view (the `Paint`). In this new ball class, a ball has a location (specified by a `PointF`), a `Paint`, and a diameter. It also has methods to get most of these variables in addition to setting some.

```
public class Ball {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private PointF mCoordinates;
    private int mDiameter;

    public Ball (int color, int diameter) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mCoordinates = new PointF();
        mCoordinates.x = 0;
        mCoordinates.y = 0;
        mDiameter = diameter;
    }

    public void setCoordinates (float x, float y) {
        mCoordinates.x = x;
        mCoordinates.y = y;
    }

    public PointF getCoordinates() {
        return mCoordinates;
    }

    public Paint getPaint() {
        return mPaint;
    }

    public int getDiameter() {
        return mDiameter;
    }

    /* You did not want to draw the uninitialized ball, so this method checks that */
    public boolean hasNonZeroLocation () {
        return (mCoordinates.x != 0 && mCoordinates.y != 0);
    }
}
```

I use the `Ball` class in the activity as shown below. Notice that the redrawing to the canvas now only occurs when a user touches the canvas as opposed to an infinite while loop. This is due to the utilization of the `Handler` class which posts actions to run to the UI thread. Additionally, now we do not need a custom view, and our ball's logic has been decoupled from the activity and the view.

```
public class RedBallActivity extends Activity {

Handler mDrawingHandler;
SurfaceView mDrawingSurfaceView;
Ball mBall;

private final Runnable drawRedBallOnBlueSurface = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!mDrawingSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface().isValid()) return;

        Canvas canvas = mDrawingSurfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        if (mBall.hasNonZeroLocation()) 
            canvas.drawCircle(mBall.getCoordinates().x, mBall.getCoordinates().y, mBall.getDiameter(), mBall.getPaint());

        mDrawingSurfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
};

private final OnTouchListener mCanvasTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        mBall.setCoordinates(event.getX(), event.getY());
        mDrawingHandler.post(drawRedBallOnBlueSurface);
        return true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    mDrawingSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
    mDrawingSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(mCanvasTouchListener);
    setContentView(mDrawingSurfaceView);
    mBall = new Ball(Color.RED, 40); 
    mDrawingHandler = new Handler();
}
}
```

Now, if you actually run this code you will notice that initially the screen is not drawn with a blue background. You might be tempted to simply call `mDrawingHandler.post(drawRedBallOnBlueSurface);` at the end of the `onCreate` method, but it is not guaranteed that the SurfaceView will be ready to be drawn upon ([see the documentation on this lockCanvas method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29)). If you want the surface to initially be blue, you need to implement a `[SurfaceHolder.Callback][2]`, which needs to be connected to the SurfaceView's SurfaceHolder, and on the `surfaceCreated` method being called, we know the surface is ready, so we can then call `mDrawingHandler.post(drawRedBallOnBlueSurface);`

Now, with this added, I change the Activity to implement `[SurfaceHolder.Callback][2]` as follows:

```
public class FriendManagerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
```

and add this line to the constructor:

```
mDrawingSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

and implement the interface:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mDrawingHandler.post(drawRedBallOnBlueSurface);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}
```

Feel free to ask any questions on my little redesign! While your problem could be easily patched, I felt like the way you were coupling logic with Views was a little bit flawed, and thought a little more info on SurfaceView coding would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As someone mentioned it in the above, when your activity ends, your thread is still running, but your custom SurfaceView is no longer available, so you will get a Null Point Exception. Your existing code can easily be patched by adding a boolean that gets set to false as soon as the onPause fn gets called:I had the same problem. To solve it I added the following onPause() to your SampleTwoView class:

```
// pause method will destroy the Thread
    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                myThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        myThread = null;
    }
```

Then call this onPause() method in your onPause() method of your Sample2 class as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SampleTwoView.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

So everytime the onPause() method of your main Activity class is called the Thread will be destroyed.
I hope this will help you.
Cheers!